# Override user registration form

Tags: 8, forms, users

I'm looking for a OOP way to have a simplified User registration form in Drupal 8.

As of today, the default User registration form is declared directly as an annotation in the User class. From the administration pages, it is possible to add a **Register** form display for the user form. However, when removing all possible fields save for the password/login, there is still a bunch of fields showing up that I want removed:

- Username
- Password confirmation
- Locales settings
- Contact settings
- etc.

What I want is an extremely simple registration form, with just two fields: **e-mail address** and **password**. All other fields will be editable later. I want this form to use OOP if possible, so extending the class **Drupal\user\RegisterForm** seems to me a good way to achieve this...

I extended the form but can't use it. It requires an entity to be passed to it apparently, but I don't know how to do that.

The ideal way to do it would be:

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('user')
  ->create([])
;
$formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getFormObject('user', 'register')
  ->setEntity($entity)
;
$registerForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);
```

However this will insist on fetching the original, non-inherited **RegisterForm** class, not my custom one. How can I tell Drupal to instanciate my own form instead?

BTW how can I make **username** optional?

I've seen a few solutions out there for redefining the user registration form, however most of them are Drupal 7 solutions and none of them are OOP.

Comment: tl;dr, username is required since email-only accounts are not supported yet. there is a huge century old issue about this.

Comment: That's fine, I'll find a way to set the Username with the e-mail. That is not the main issue here.

Comment: To make username as optional you can use the Email Registration module which make Email address as required field.

https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration

Through Manage Display Under Configuration > People > Account Settings
 you can disable the fields that you don't want.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the extended register form class, you need to put it in the place of the original form class in the user entity type:

*mymodule.module*

```
  /**
   * Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
   */
  function mymodule_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
    $entity_types['user']->setFormClass('register', 'Drupal\mymodule\MyRegisterForm');
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to [create a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules) and add a service:

@file: *my_module.services.yml*

```
  services:
    route_subscriber:
      class: Drupal\my_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber
      tags:
        - {name: event_subscriber }
```

@file: *src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php*

```
  /**
   * @file
   * Contains \Drupal\my_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber.
   */

  namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;

  use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

  /**
   * Listens to the dynamic route events.
   */
  class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      // login form
      if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
        $route->setDefault('_form', '\Drupal\my_module\Form\NewUserLoginForm');
      }
      // register form
      if ($route = $collection->get('user.register')) {
        $route->setDefault('_form', '\Drupal\my_module\Form\NewUserRegisterForm');
      }

    }
  }
```

and a custom form class:

@file: *src/Form/NewUserRegisterForm.php*

```
  /**
   * @file
   * Contains \Drupal\my_module\Form\NewUserRegisterForm.
   *
   * credits to: https://gist.github.com/davidDuymelinck/cd20ab7049749358717127f12666b68c
   */

  namespace Drupal\my_module\Form;

  use Drupal\Component\Datetime\TimeInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilderInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeBundleInfoInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
  use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
  use Drupal\user\RegisterForm;
  use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

  /**
   * Provides a user register form.
   */
  class NewUserRegisterForm extends RegisterForm {
      public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entity_manager, LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager, EntityTypeBundleInfoInterface $entity_type_bundle_info = NULL, TimeInterface $time = NULL, ModuleHandlerInterface $moduleHandler) {
          $this->setEntity(new User([], 'user'));
          $this->setModuleHandler($moduleHandler);
          parent::__construct($entity_manager, $language_manager, $entity_type_bundle_info, $time);
      }
      /**
       * @inheritdoc
       */
      public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
          return new static(
              $container->get('entity.manager'),
              $container->get('language_manager'),
              $container->get('entity_type.bundle.info'),
              $container->get('datetime.time'),
              $container->get('module_handler')
          );
      }
      public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
          $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);
          $form['test'] = [
              '#markup' => '<p>Test extended form</p>',
          ];

          return $form;
      }
  }
```

**NB:** I did not find how to alter/modify the submit button because `$form` has no *actions* key.

Comment: Btw if you modify the class in the user entity type the route will be generated automatically to call the form handler (and to set the new entity which is needed to run the entity form).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the REST resources for creating users instead of hooking into Drupal classes. It is much easier and your frontend guys can completely control the registration experience.

1. Enable REST and REST UI
2. Enable /user/register REST route
3. Edit permissions for this route adding "anonymous access"
4. Now you send JSON objects to /user/register via ajax
5. Example:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: Drupal.url('user/register?_format=json'),
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: JSON.stringify(userForm),
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
           'Content-type': 'application/json'
       },
   }).done(function(response) {
     console.log('done')
     console.log(response)
   }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
     console.log( JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText))
   });
   ```
6. Now your registration form HTML is completely customizable.